# What icons used in Inkscape UI?

Tags: inkscape

Maybe it's offtop, sorry if it is. I search for PNG/SVG icons files used in **Inkscape** UI, ie, "open file", "save file", "options" etc-- which are nice and I want to use them maybe.

What are these icos?

Comment: InkScape is open source. Have you browsed its files? (But note these icons may have been designed by artists speficially for InkScape.)

Comment: Yes, i searched for PNGs and found 10-15, not ok, not toolbar ones.

Answer (score 3):

It is a Tango icons set. You can find it [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Tango_icons).

Answer (score 1):

I found "icons.svg" ("shared" dir of installed app) which are all icons on one SVG canvas.
Bad that I can't use this svg (need PNGs, cannot easy make them).

Comment: Write a for loop and turn them into png's

Comment: I don't know IS that much, only can view svgs.

Comment: @RProgram [Export](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/File-Export.html) function of Inkscape exports the selection or the image as PNG.

Comment: But single SVG for all. Not one per icon..

Comment: @RProgram *Select* the desired icon and *export* it at the desired resolution. Try... is not difficult.